# Force Java Swing window to floating mode

Tags: java, swing, floating, i3

I use i3 tiling manager. Was wondering how to force Java Swing windows to floating mode. See python's tkinter solution:

[How to make tkinter Window floating in i3 windowmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35830851/13850406)

tl;dr:

```
root = Tk()
root.attributes('-type', 'dialog')'
```

Comment: Are you referring to a [JDialog or JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)?

Comment: Do you know about modal windows? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481405/how-to-make-a-jframe-modal-in-swing-java